# QuickMapServices not showing anything

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, basemap, quickmapservices

I have seen that this issue has already been reported in the past but for previous QGIS versions. So, I decided to raise it again and, in the case it would be considered a repetition, I excuse.

I am using QGIS 3.16.0-Hannover and QuickMapServices (QMS) version 0.19.11.1.
QMS was working while, all of a sudden, it stopped showing basemaps. I mean every basemaps available for QMS.

Maybe it's my fault because I could have changed some settings but I really do not know what to do.

Comment: Please use the corresponding [GitHub-Site](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/issues) for this report. GIS.SE is not the place to report such things.

Comment: If you don't recall the settings you changed, maybe you could completely reinstall QGIS and start over.

Comment: @Stu Smith  sorry, maybe what I wrote was not clear. I did not change anything. Indeed I have tried to uninstall and then to reinstall it again but the problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that reinstalling didn't help, I empathize with you!  FWIW, I just removed 3.14.16 (which had the QMS plugin installed), and upgraded to 3.16.1.  Fortunately, QMS still works for me just fine at 3.16.1.  Thus, I suspect your problem is not with QGIS or QMS, but some other issue.  Good luck, and please report back when you find a solution.